# sql many to many relationship where do I put type field

Tags: sql

If I have the following tables listed below, would I want to put the AddressTypeID in the Address table or the CompanyAddress table?

COMPANY
CompanyID

COMPANYADDRESS
CompanyAddressID
CompanyID
AddressID

ADDRESS
AddressID

ADDRESSTYPE
AddressTypeID

Answer (score 1):

First, stop to think about whether this is really a many-to-many relationship. Will you ever really assign the exact same address record to more than one company? You may be able to simplify your design by eliminating `CompanyAddress` and adding a `CompanyID` column directly to `Address`.

If this truly is a many-to-many relationship, then to answer your original question, keep the `AddressTypeID` in `Address`, not in `CompanyAddress`, since it should be the same type for every company that uses it.

Comment: It sounds weird,  but yes I can have the same address for different companies, that's why I set it up this way.  I had AddressTypeID in the address table, but I just wanted to make sure that was correct, thanks for the answer

Comment: @user1220099: Fair enough. Just wanted to make sure you'd thought the design through, and you have.